# EntityFrameworkCore for Sqlite not creating __EFMigrationHistory table

Tags: sqlite, uwp, entity-framework-core

Before I explain my issue, I have some experience with entity framework 5 and 6 code first migrations, running `add-migration`/`update-database` and a few more specific commands from the Package Manager console. All of the migration history was handled out of the box in the `__MigrationHistory` table.

I am now writing a UWP app and using `EntityFrameworkCore` sqlite. The app is set up to scaffold new migrations and does so correctly.

When applying migrations the app needs to automatically deduce, on install and first startup, if the database exists, and the current database migration version. It can then apply the relevant migration procedures, including creating the database if required.

Currently, I attempt to perform the migrations in my DbContext on startup:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{        
    public DbSet<SomeEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }

    static MyContext()
    {
        using(var db = new MyContext())
        {
            db.Database.Migrate();
        }
    }
```

This works perfectly for a new app on first startup. On second startup however, or after the addition of a new migration, the Migrate() method fails as the tables it is attempting to create already exist.

> > SQLite Error 1: 'table \"MyEntities\" already exists'

This error comes from rerunning the migration that has been previously applied. The database itself needs to be aware of it's migration history as was previously handled with `__EFMigrationHistory`. Currently this table is not being created for me.

I am suspecting that I need to manually build a solution to this, maybe creating my own __MigrationHistory table and keeping it up to date, as per this post [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6273#issuecomment-239919733)

I wondered what solutions people have used for this issue, or if there is anything out of the box that I'm being silly and missing.

Let me know if more detail needed.

Comment: Or maybe you made some model changes that require the table to be rebuilt (SQLite does not support ADD/DELETE COLUMN and many other DDL operations)

Comment: That wouldn't explain the Migrate failing on the second run though would it? e.g. If I delete the db, and run, the database creates/migrates perfectly. then, with no model changes, if I run again it fails when attempting to rerun the previously performed migration.

Comment: No, there should be a Migration History table - did you follow the guid here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started ?

Comment: @ErikEJ Thanks for the article. I didn't actually set up this project myself I'm just exploring this issue. But the setup is identical to that article yes, I've been through step by step. If EF is creating the tables but not the MigrationHistory, have you any idea what could be to blame? SOrry, I know this is somewhat vague

Comment: I usually add a setting to my app to let me know if the migration has been run yet.  I only do the migration the first time the app is run after the database is changed

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in a manner of speaking but I'm still not sure why the `__MigrationHistory` table was not automatically generated...

I couldn't find any evidence of other people struggling with this issue in UWP apps, so it is likely project specific and something caused by how the solution was set up.

Anyway, the changes I made:

I created a `MigrationHistory` model and added it as a `DbSet` to my DbContext.

Model

```
namespace MyApp.Shared.Models.Infrastructure
{
    public class MigrationHistory
    {
        public string MigrationId { get; set; }
        public string ProductVersion { get; set; }
    }
}
```

DbContext additions

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{        

    public DbSet<MigrationHistory> __MigrationHistory { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        #region Primary Keys

        modelBuilder.Entity<MigrationHistory>().HasKey(mh => mh.MigrationId);
```

At this stage, on running add-migration entity framework attempted to create the `__MigrationHistory` table. This would result in an error if I ran my application, as applying the migration would result in the error:

> > SQLite Error 1: 'table \"__MigrationHistory\" already exists'

So I added the following code to my `MyContextModelSnapshot` class

```
modelBuilder.Entity("MyApp.Shared.Models.Infrastructure.MigrationHistory", b =>
{
    b.Property<string>("MigrationId")
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

    b.Property<string>("ProductVersion");

    b.HasKey("MigrationId");

    b.ToTable("__MigrationHistory");
});
```

Once it is in the snapshot, it can stay there, and it acts to prevent entity framework attempting to add this table in future migrations.

On startup my app now runs

```
using (var db = new Assessment.Data.WindowsUniversal.AssessmentContext())
{
            db.MigrateDatabase();
}
```

And it works perfectly, consulting the table and applying migrations where necessary.

I feel like this is a solution to a problem that doesn't really exist, and that is of my own making, but I'll leave this here in case it's relevant to somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i've come up with while having your same issue, i found out the **debug** database (inside your \bin\Debug folder) won't have the __EFMigrationsHistory table, while the **production** database (root of your launching project) has it.

Maybe could be of help for somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue with Sqlite In-Memory databases in my Tests. I have found the following thread https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/4922. The point is ones all connections to the database are closed, the database is being removed from the memory. I have not solved the issue yet as I started using physical databases instead. But I will update my answer ones I find the solution.

My problem is even if I call `db.Database.Migrate()` first time without any other connections opened before, it still throws such error.